# Postgres createdb and create database is not working in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, ubuntu

I have a Django project I am trying to set up on Ubuntu and am creating a new database in PostgreSQL 14.

The default root user is Postgres as usual.

Then I tried creating a new user with my Linux username "abc" with all the privileges: "SUPERUSER", "CREATEDB", etc. Everything worked fine and a new user was created.

And it was suggested that I create a database with the same name "abc".

> So, I did  `CREATE DATABASE abc;` in the psql shell, it gives no error and results in nothing.

> I tried `createdb abc` or `creatdb` in the bash terminal but this also does nothing either.

The solution from this SO answer  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321005/postgresql-not-creating-db-with-createdb-as-superuser-yet-not-outputting-erro) does not work for me at all.

I also tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/560895/postgres-createdb-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04) which did not do anything.

I ultimately just want to be able to create the database for my Django project, which I am not able to do, and I have now no clue what I am doing wrong.

Here's the command I am using to set up the Django project db:

```
# create new user who will be the db owner
# on Ubuntu, root user is postgres
createuser -P <new_user_name> -U <root_user>

# if you're having issues logging in
# see https://stackoverflow.com/a/18664239/3187043

# create new db with the above created user as its owner
createdb -E UTF8 --lc-collate=en_IN.UTF-8 --lc-ctype=en_IN.UTF-8 -T template0 -O <new_user_name> -U <root_user> <new_db_name>
# this doesn't get created

# copy the contents to your new db
psql -U <new_user_name> <new_db_name> < ~/Downloads/backup-ocrdb-2018-09-13_1214.psql
#fails with no output

# Log in to psql console using
psql -U <new_user_name> <new_db_name>
#unable to login because db has not been created
```

As suggested by @Laurenz Albe

Here is the output of running : `SELECT * FROM pg_locks;`

[image]

Comment: Must be a typo.

Comment: I have done it a lot of time, I dont think it will be due to a typo.

Comment: Maybe it's a Windows problem because I m doing it inside WSL2.

Comment: I also tried to create the DB using the Pgadmin dashboard, and it takes forever and doesn't create it.

Comment: If it hangs and does not finish, that sounds like a lock. Look at the PostgreSQL log for interesting messages. While `CREATE DATABASE` hangs, run `SELECT * FROM pg_locks;` in a second database session and add the result to the question.

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62186945/why-pgadmin-4-is-too-slow), I have the same issue, but the solutions are not helpful.

Comment: Did you try what I recommended?

Comment: PostgreSQL log is not opening due to the same issue. I'll do the second part soon.